# am in the Desktop but I cd is not see the desktop

Tags: linux

[image]

How can I fixs that problem meanwhie I fix last code Selenim
Selenium but I am take same error. And cd is not see the Desktop but I am in the Desktop.

Answer (score 3):

Here `~` is equal to `/home/levidonates` so when you type `cd ~/Selenium` it's actually `cd /home/levidonates/Selenium` but the folder `Selenium` is in your folder `Desktop`, so you need to type :

`cd ~/Desktop/Selenium`

Comment: I have to every time write the exact path.

Comment: You can also type `cd Selenium` instead, which will guide you to `Selenium`, if you are in `~/Desktop`

Comment: The shell also has tab completion, so use it.

Comment: @levitomato Another thing, don't type `cd /Desktop` but just `cd Desktop` because `/` in linux is the root but your Desktop folder is not in the root but in your home

Answer (score 1):

`~` is a shorthand for your home directory, `/home/levidomates`. The directories you're accessing are under there, not under the root, `/`. That is, `~/Desktop` is not the same as `/Desktop`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I see which folder do you try to enter / at the beginning? this is not true method.
/ characters means top of all folders root level.
You should not confuse it with the root user's home folder.
cd: change directory
cd .. : Back to the previous folder or up folder.

Firstly You can check your home folder

```
echo $HOME
```

then you must be enter pwd
if the your home folder `/home/levidomates/`
you must only `cd ~` command
than `cd Desktop`

You shouldn't use / at the beginning of folders

Answer (score 0):

Your absolute way to Deskotp is not correct...You forgot /home/levidomates
So then it should be cd /home/levidomates/Desktop instead of cd /Desktop